# Problem moving the WordPress WooCommerce term description

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I am under WordPress with the WooCommerce plugin, my problem is that I would like to reverse the list of products and the description, many solutions exist but each time I have the description on TOP AND BOTTOM, while I would like to have only at the bottom

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have attached a guide for the hooks on a single product and another guide on how to use the. If you follow the guide you can move things around as you would like.

woocommerce single product hooks - https://www.businessbloomer.com/woocommerce-visual-hook-guide-single-product-page/

How to use woocommerce hooks - https://www.commercegurus.com/woocommerce-hooks/

Answer (score 0):

Usually you may edit the pages layout , sometimes , there will be a bug so apply the debug mode to check .

Comment: Please use comments for this type of suggestions.